# How to show that antiderivative of $x^x(1+\ln x)$ is equal to $x^x + C$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I know that derivative of 
$$y=x^x$$ is equal to $$\frac{dy}{dx}=x^x(1+\ln(x)).$$ 
For antiderivative I take integration of the both sides and get
$$y=\int\big(x^x(1+\ln(x))\big)dx$$, using integration by parts 
$$\Rightarrow y=(1+\ln(x))\int x^x dx-\int\bigg(\frac{d}{dx}(1+\ln x) \int x^x dx\bigg)dx$$
$$\Rightarrow y=(1+\ln(x))\int x^x dx-\int\bigg(\frac{1}{x} \int x^x dx\bigg)dx$$
How to proceed further to get $$y=x^x +c$$, I don't know

Comment: There is nothing to prove. This is just the definition of anti-derivative.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Exactly, but apparently some people don't know their definitions, and are even ingrates when we point out such things to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the change of variable $u=x \ln(x)$.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because I think what this question really wanted, or at least needed, was an explanation of how you could *get* the antiderivative without first *knowing* it, not simply reminders that the FTC tells us how to verify one we already have.

Answer (score 2):

You can write $$ x^{x} = e^{xlnx} $$ then $$\int\big(x^x(1+\ln(x))\big)dx$$ will become $$\int\big(e^{xlnx}(1+\ln(x))\big)dx$$ and that is nothing but $$e^{xlnx}+c$$ since the derivative of $x*lnx$ is nothing but $1+lnx$.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that $\mathrm dy/\mathrm dx=f(x),$ where $y=y(x),$ then it follows by definition that the primitives of $f(x)$ are of the form $y+c,$ with $c$ being an arbitrary constant.

So, your first couple of lines are all the proof you need.

Comment: Assume that perhaps he worked out the derivative by hand, and wants to verify it instead. Maybe he made a mistake, you never know. In that light, this feels like a cheap workaround. Yes the derivative is right, but how about we verify it without using that fact?

Comment: @Allawonder I know about the result but how to get it, integrating, the left hand side of the last equation!

Comment: @NoorAslam Then your question is misleading: You clearly asked that you wanted to show that the primitive of a certain function is another. One does that simply by differentiating the latter.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer What are you talking about? If one wants to show that a certain function is a primitive of another, one simply differentiates the latter to get the former. There's nothing else to check.

Answer (score 0):

By change of variables:
$$\int x^x\left(1+\ln x\right)dx=\int d(x^x)=x^x+C$$